# How to replace multiple substrings in a dataframe using replacement dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, substring

I have a dataframe like this
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['[A]', '[A][B]', '[A][B][C]', '[A] [D]',
'[D]', '[D][B]', '[D][B][C]', '[D][B][C][E]', '[F]', '[G]', '[H]']})

I want to replace using python regex to get this type of replacement using python and regex:

A with M
B with Z
C with P
D with Q
E with L
F with V
G with S
H with R

`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['[A]', '[A][B]', '[A][B][C]', '[A] [D]', '[D]', '[D][B]', '[D][B][C]', '[D][B][C][E]', '[F]', '[G]', '[H]']})

replacement_mapping = {
    'A': 'M',
    'B': 'Z',
    'C': 'P',
    'D': 'Q',
    'E': 'L',
    'F': 'V',
    'G': 'S',
    'H': 'R'
}

for old_value, new_value in replacement_mapping.items():
    df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(f'[{old_value}]', f'[{new_value}]')

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: `df['col'] = ["".join([replacement_mapping.get(c, c) for c in item]) for item in df['col']]` - one liner i ncase if you prefer